# Knockout ObservableArray not getting updated in UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to update the array value bound to ObservaleArray. However its not getting updated.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Title=ko.observable('Sample');
    self.people = ko.observableArray([
         new Person('Ajay'),
         new Person('Kumar')
    ]);

    self.updateAns=function(){
     self.people()[0].Answered=false;
    };

    self.updateName=function(){
     self.people()[0].Name('John');
    };
    self.updateTitle=function(){
     self.Title('New Title');
    };

}

var Person=function(name){
  this.Name=name;
  this.Answer=[{Id: 1, Answered:true},{Id:2, Answered:true}]
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

[Full Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GOzWtoKETPSLYaptHWFY?p=preview)

How to keep the array value sync?

Answer (score 1):

The observable array will only listen to changes to the array itself, you also need the members onthe Person to be observables if you want them to update

Comment: The person data i get from server is an array. Do i need to create another object and decorate each property as ko.observable? Is there a way to decorate whole object like ko.observable(object) instead of wiring each property?

Comment: Yes, you need to create ViewModel representations of your Model. You can use the Mapping plugin or do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Observable array tracks changes of a [collection of things](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). Meaning it doesn't detect changes of array items, but only changes of the collection, like add/remove/replace elements. In order to keep Person `name` value in sync it should be `observable`.

```
var Person = function(name){
  this.Name = ko.observable(name);
  ...
}
```

[Updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WficUp6O07Cox0upQW1F?p=preview)

Comment: The person data i get from server is an array. Do i need to create another object and decorate each property as ko.observable? Is there a way to decorate whole object like ko.observable(object) instead of wiring each property?

Comment: In that case you might want to look at knockouts mapping plugin : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html which can automatically create observables for you

Comment: @Billa Yes, you can do this. Another way would be using [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).